# Postgres connection problem in docker-compose up in Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

My Django project **works fine** with **python manage.py runserver** with no problem. Postgres, redis, django, djangorestframework all fine together.

I try to Dockerize the project, but I get the following error for Postgres:

```
....
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here's my docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  database-data:
```

Note: I also tried an alternative postgres repo:
https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem, it was about the settings:

In my settings.py, HOST value was 127.0.0.1, I changed it to 'db', this solved everything....

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'bigdata',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```